# Which passport to use for airline check-in for dual citizenship

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, check-in

I am a Canadian living in Canada with another citizenship from a country (Country A) that does not recognize dual citizenship.  Citizens of Country A needs visa to enter Canada.

Will be travelling to Country A from Canada soon.  Very confused as to which passport to use for airline checkin in Canada and Canada immigration.  Which passport for entering Country A.  For returning to Canada, which passport to use for airline checkin in Country A and Country A immigration.

Comment: I suspect the answer varies greatly depending on what County A is. For instance, we had a question [for China](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66740/i-have-booked-a-flight-from-the-usa-to-china-and-am-a-dual-national-how-do-i-av), where the answer is complicated, as China doesn't merely "not recognize" dual citizenship; it takes steps to prohibit it. Many other countries are passively fine with dual citizenship, as long as you don't do something nutty like try to claim consular protection from one country while you're "home" in the other. In short, knowing which country matters.

Comment: It would help if you could name a country...

Answer (score 0):

At Canadian check-in you Show both passports.

Canadian immigration? There's no Immigration control when leaving Canada, period.

For entering Country A, you obviously use that country's passport.

On the way back, again, at check-in you Show both passports, while at Immigration, you Show the passport of Country A. For Canadian Immigration, the Canadian passport.

Comment: That depends on how serious Country A is about not liking dual citizenships. For example, it may have passed a law requiring airline check-in agents to snitch on travelers who are suspected to have two passport. In that case the journey will only be safely possible with a stopover in a third country that the OP can enter with her A passport.